# Using setter method to update specific field of specific ID in Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a switch which sets the status of a User (that is saved in a database) between active and inactive.

I've tried the below code and the text on screen changes, but the entry in the database is not updated. Am I missing some code that updates the User entry?

```
statusSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
        userProfile.observe(UserServiceStatus.this,
            new Observer<UserProfile>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable UserProfile sections) {
                    if (isChecked) {              
                        tvStatusDescription.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.user_profile_status_active));
                        userProfile.getValue().setStatus(isChecked);
                    } else {
                        tvStatusDescription.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.user_profile_status_inactive));
                        userProfile.getValue().setStatus(isChecked);
                    }
               }
           });
       }
});
```

Comment: Use LiveData and you must run update query in UserDAO

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh Can I use `@Update void update(UserProfile userProfile);` and choose to only update the Status field for it?

Comment: you must have run update query anytime if you want to update data. when data updated, if you use Livedata, ui will update too

Comment: I tried using `userProfileDao.update(userProfile);` and changed the method to take in `LiveData<userProfile>` as a parameter, but it says I need to annotate it as @Entity. When I do that, it says the annotation is not applicable to this method.

Comment: see this:https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: I think it's very clear to understand, try codelab of google: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0

Comment: I understand how I can retrieve database entries based on conditions, and I managed to update entries, but couldn't find a specific example on how to update only a single field of an entry. I can't find an example either in the documentations you provided, could you point me to it? (Apologies - I'm a bit of a beginner with Room)

Comment: You need creat one filed in your database to check status of User like isSave of isSelected, something like that, value default is 0, when you click you run update query you update that filed equal 1.





and when you get data with LiveData, check if(isSvae ==0){}else if(isSvae == 1){}{}. When you click and update User, your data will be update automatically in UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204117/discussion-between-george-and-hoang-v-anh).